# Unity 2D How to get Object that is being overlapped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have blocks in a scene and I move a block with the mouse. Each block has a BoxCollider2D attached. I am trying to figure out which block it is that I bumped into.  I can't use Rigidbody to detect collisions as I don't want any physics applied. I know how to detect if the object I am moving is overlapping a point but I don't know how to get the object that I am overlapping?

Comment: Use one of the `BoxCast` functions to see if your collider is overlapping any other collider: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need physics/rigidbody to use colliders; just set the colliders as triggers and use the `OnTrigger` method.